# Cocos2d EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, release, exc-bad-access, ipad-2

I am new to cocos2d and suddenly got this EXC_BAD_ACCESS,
I made a new winning menu and i got the error
I think the error is because i called a released object, but i dont release anything?
My Debug Console had no error, which is strange

here is my Level_1.m

```
//
//  Level_1.m
//  iPadGame
//
//  Created by My Name on 1/25/12.
//  Copyright 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Level_1.h"
#import "HelloWorldLayer.h"

CCSprite *player;
CCSprite *enemy;
CCSprite *enemy2;
CCSprite *enemy3;
CCSprite *star;
CCSprite *star2;
CCSprite *star3;
CCSprite *bg;
CCSprite *toolBar;

CCLabelTTF *youWin;

bool movePlayer;


@implementation Level_1

@synthesize score;

+(CCScene *) scene {
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    Level_1 *layer = [Level_1 node];

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}

-(void) setUpWinMenu {
    [CCMenuItemFont setFontName:@"Marker Felt"];
    [CCMenuItemFont setFontSize:75];
    CCMenuItem *MainMenu = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Main Menu" target:self selector:@selector(gotoMainMenu)];
    CCMenu *WinMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:MainMenu, nil];
    [self addChild:WinMenu];
    MainMenu.position = ccp(400,500);

}
// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
-(id) init
{
    // always call "super" init
    // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super" return value
    if( (self=[super init])) 
    {
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

        scoreNumber = 10;

        bg = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"metal_background.jpeg"];
        bg.position = ccp(512,384);
        [self addChild:bg];

        toolBar = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ToolBar.png"];
        toolBar.position = ccp(512,-30);
        [self addChild:toolBar];

        score = [CCLabelAtlas labelWithString:@"0123456789" charMapFile:@"ScoreFinal.png" itemWidth:50 itemHeight:75 startCharMap:'.'];
        [self addChild:score];
        score.position = ccp (-100,15);

        CCLabelTTF *scoreLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Score:" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:45];
        scoreLabel.position = ccp(score.position.x + 275,score.position.y + 40);
        scoreLabel.color = ccc3(0, 0, 0);
        [self addChild:scoreLabel];



        star = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Star.png"];
        star.position = ccp(400,600);
        [self addChild:star];

        star2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Star.png"];
        star2.position = ccp(600,600);

        star3 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Star.png"];
        star3.position = ccp(200,600);

        player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ball.png"];
        player.position = ccp(500,300);
        [self addChild:player];

        enemy = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"SpaceShip.png"];
        enemy.position = ccp(150,600);
        [self addChild:enemy];

        enemy2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"SpaceShip.png"];
        enemy2.position = ccp(250,600);
        [self addChild:enemy2];

        enemy3 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"SpaceShip.png"];
        enemy3.position = ccp(350,600);
        [self addChild:enemy3];

        [self schedule:@selector(enemyMove) interval:0.01];
        [self schedule:@selector(collisionDetection) interval:0.01];
        [self schedule:@selector(getStar) interval:0.01];

        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i", (int)scoreNumber];
        [score setString:string];

        x = 15;
        x2 = 15;
        x3 = 15;
        y = 15;

        Bx = 10;
        By = 10;

        movePlayer = FALSE;
        CCRepeatForever *repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:2 angle:360]];
        [star runAction:repeat];

        star.visible = 1;

    }
    return self;
}


-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch* myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView: [myTouch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];


    CGRect playerRect = CGRectMake(player.position.x - (player.contentSize.width/2),
                                   player.position.y - (player.contentSize.height/2),
                                   player.contentSize.width,
                                   player.contentSize.height);

    CGRect Tlocation = CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, 10, 10);



    NSLog(@"Touch Began");
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect (Tlocation, playerRect)) {
        player.position = location;
        movePlayer = TRUE;
    }



}

-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
    point = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:point];

    if (movePlayer == TRUE) {
        player.position = point;

        if (player.position.y < 110) {
            player.position = ccp(player.position.x, 111);
        }
    }

}

-(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Touch ended");

    movePlayer = FALSE;

}

-(void) enemyMove {
    enemy.position = ccp(enemy.position.x + x, enemy.position.y);
    enemy2.position = ccp(enemy2.position.x - x2, enemy2.position.y);
    enemy3.position = ccp(enemy3.position.x + x3, enemy3.position.y);

    if (enemy.position.x > 1024 || enemy.position.x < 0) {
        x = -x;
    }
    if (enemy2.position.x > 1024 || enemy2.position.x < 0) {
        x2 = -x2;
    }
    if (enemy3.position.x > 1024 || enemy3.position.x < 0) {
        x3 = -x3;
    }
    if (enemy.position.y > 768 || enemy.position.y < 120) {
        y = -y;
    }

}

-(void) collisionDetection {
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(player.boundingBox, enemy.boundingBox)) {
        [self schedule:@selector(collisionAlert)];
    }
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(player.boundingBox, enemy2.boundingBox)) {
        [self schedule:@selector(collisionAlert)];
    }
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(player.boundingBox, enemy3.boundingBox)) {
        [self schedule:@selector(collisionAlert)];
    }
}

-(void) getStar {
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(player.boundingBox, star.boundingBox)) {

        NSLog(@"Got Star!");

        scoreNumber += 100;
        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i", (int)scoreNumber];
        [score setString:string];

        [self addChild:star2];

        if (star.visible == 1) {

        }
    }
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(player.boundingBox, star2.boundingBox)) {

        NSLog(@"Got Star!");

        scoreNumber += 100;
        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i", (int)scoreNumber];
        [score setString:string];

        [self addChild:star3];
    }
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(player.boundingBox, star3.boundingBox)) {
        youWin = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"You Win" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:75];
        youWin.position = ccp(500,400);
        [self addChild:youWin];
        [self setUpWinMenu];
        NSLog(@"Got Star!");


        scoreNumber += 100;
        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i", (int)scoreNumber];
        [score setString:string];

        player.position = ccp(player.position.x - 10, player.position.y - 20);
        [self unschedule:@selector(enemyMove)];
        [self unschedule:@selector(collisionAlert)];
        [self unschedule:@selector(getStar)];

    }


    return;
}
-(void) collisionAlert {
    player.position = ccp(player.position.x - 10, player.position.y - 20);
    [self unschedule:@selector(enemyMove)];
    UIAlertView* dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    [dialog setDelegate:self];
    [dialog setTitle:@"Fail"];
    [dialog setMessage:@"You are a Failure!"];
    [dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Goto Main Menu"];
    [dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Retry!"];
    [dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Dont push this button"];
    [dialog show];
    [dialog release];
    [self unschedule:@selector(collisionAlert)];
}
-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(buttonIndex == 0) {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFlipAngular transitionWithDuration:1 scene:[HelloWorldLayer node]]];
    }
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[Level_1 node]];
    }
    if (buttonIndex == 2) {

        [self schedule:@selector(noting)];
    }
}

-(void) gotoMainMenu {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionJumpZoom transitionWithDuration:1 scene:[HelloWorldLayer node]]];
}

@end
```

im not finished completely but there maybe a few empty methods but im sure thats not whats causing the problem

Comment: Basic debugging tips: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/10/xcode-4-debugging-crashcourse/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All this objects:

```
CCSprite *player;
CCSprite *enemy;
CCSprite *enemy2;
CCSprite *enemy3;
CCSprite *star;
CCSprite *star2;
CCSprite *star3;
CCSprite *bg;
CCSprite *toolBar;
```

are being allocated with autorelease methods, such as `CCSprite spriteWithFile:` and then, when you access these objects in other methods, like you do at `ccTouchesBegan: withEvent:` they are already deallocated, and you get the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

One thing you can do to fix it, is to call the `spriteWithFile:` method followed by a retain call, like

```
toolBar = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ToolBar.png"] retain];
```

But don't forget to release the retained objects on your Level_1's class `dealloc` (which I didn't see implemented in your class)

```
-(void) dealloc {

   [toolBar release];
   [super dealloc]
}
```

Comment: @FelipSabino I don't understand why in `ccTouchesBegan: withEvent:` they are already deallocated if they are added as child to the layer. Shouldn't they be retained if they are added as child?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't see anything on the console, if you run the app under the debugger, you should be able to inspect the call stack at the moment of the crash.

This will tell you clearly if you are accessing some already deallocated object, or possibly trying to send a message.